# Conditional probability and pdf and cdf

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ describes the waiting time for a random event to happen, and X has a known pdf $f(x)$ and cdf $F(x)$.   Let $Y$ be the random variable (r.v.) describe the waiting time for an event to happen in the same random process, conditioning on $X > x_0$.

1. What is the pdf for $Y$ ?   Express it in terms of $f (x)$ and/or $F (x)$.
2. Suppose $X$ is an exponential r.v. with parameter $a$, what is $f(x)$?   What is the pdf for $Y$ ?   How do you interpret this?   (Hint: Exponential distributions are known to be ”memoryless”)

Comment: @Henry: In fact, I have no idea about the correlation between X and Y, so I don't know how to get the pdf for Y based on X. Could you show me any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- What is $\Pr(X \gt x_0)$?
- What is $\Pr(X \gt y)$?
- Assuming $y \gt x_0$, what is $\Pr(X \gt y \mid X \gt x_0)$?
- Assuming $y \gt x_0$, what is $\Pr(X \le y \mid X \gt x_0)$?

That last result is the cumulative distribution function for $Y$ given $X \gt x_0$.  Can you find the probability density function?

Comment: Pr(X>x0)=1-Fx(x0),Pr(X>y)=1-Fx(y),Pr(X>y | X>x0)=Pr(X>y,X>x0)/Pr(X>x0)=Pr(X>y)/Pr(X>x0)=(1-Fx(y))/(1-Fx(x0)),Pr(X<=y | X>x0)=1-(1-Fx(y))/(1-Fx(x0)), this is the cdf for Y? The pdf for Y is fx(y)/(1-Fx(x0)). So the pdf for Y is f(x)/(1-F(x))?

Comment: @Emily essentially yes (it might be clearer if you used $\LaTeX$), though it might be worth adding that the pdf is $0$ when $y \le x_0$.  Part 2 should now be relatively easy